# how to get more lines from xml feed php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi i have for exmaple this is feed in xml.

```
 <SHOPITEM>
<NAME>Snubní prsteny z oceli pro páry</NAME>
<SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
<p>Cena je za 1 prsten</p><p>Snubní prsteny z chirurgické oceli</p>
</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
<SUPPLIER>Eshop-Sperku</SUPPLIER>
<WARRANTY>24</WARRANTY>
<ITEM_TYPE>product</ITEM_TYPE>
<UNIT>ks</UNIT>
<CATEGORIES>
<CATEGORY>Šperky</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>Šperky > Prsteny</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>Šperky > Prsteny > Dámské prsteny</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>Šperky > Prsteny > Pánské prsteny</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>Šperky > Prsteny > Snubní prsteny</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY>MEGA VÝPRODEJ > 30% sleva</CATEGORY>
</CATEGORIES>
```

how i get last CATEGORY in categories ?

i use now code like this:

```
 // Load xml file else check connection
   $xml = simplexml_load_file(feed.xml)
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    
   // Assign values
   foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
       $name = $row->NAME;
```

Thanks

Comment: It really helps if your demo code is valid PHP or whatever

Comment: You can get to the categories using `$xml->CATEGORIES->children()`

Comment: or `$xml->xpath('//CATEGORY[last()]')[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('users.xml')
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    
$kids =  $xml->CATEGORIES->children();

echo $kids[count($kids)-1];
```